# Распределение слов по ячейкам таблицы

Tags: javascript

Есть многомерный массив.

```
var array = [
    [
        'один',
        'два',
        'три',
        'четыре'

        // всего 16 букв
    ]
];
```

Список слов из `array[0]` должен быть размещен в таблицу, каждая буква - это отдельная ячейка таблицы. Расположение слов в таблице - не имеет значения. Главная задача - оставить их читаемыми по одной из сторон.

```
|о|д|и|н|     |ч|е|т|ы|
|ч|е|р|т|     |т|д|о|р|
|е|т|ы|р|     |р|в|д|е|
|д|в|а|и| или |и|а|и|н|
```

Мне кажется что вставить их без разбора на буквы - нереально. Вся проблема в том, что некоторые слова могут быть "закручены" (не знаю как правильно сказать). Пример:

```
| | | | |     |ч|е|т|ы|
|ч|е|р| |     | | | |р|
|е|т|ы| |     | | | |е|
| | | | | или | | | | |
```

Разбор слов на буквы:

```
for(var value = 0; value < array[0].length; value++) { 
    for (var index = 0; index < array[0][value].length; index++) { 
        // console.log(array[0][value][index]);
    } 
}
```

Важные нюансы:

1. Общее количество букв может быть больше чем 16.
2. Ячеек по горизонтали может быть больше чем 4. По задумки их количество указывается опционально `var cells = 4;`.
3. Ячеек по вертикали может быть ровно столько - сколько требуется для
   размещения всех слов.
4. Пустых ячеек быть не должно.

Пример:

```
cells = 4     cells = 4
| | | | |     | | | | |
| | | | |     | | | | |
| | | | |     | | | | |
| | | | | или | | | | |
16 букв       | | | | |
              20 букв
```

Над этой задачей я сижу 3й день, с 10:00 до 23:00. Очень сложный для меня алгоритм. Буду рад любой помощи, любым советам относительно реализации.

Comment: Пожалуйста, перестаньте задавать тот же вопрос снова и снова. Если у вас попросили уточнить вопрос - надо уточнить существующий, исправив его. Если вас не устраивают внесенные правки других участников - откатывайте их.

Comment: @hedgehogues, вы внесли 6 правок в это вопрос, на ревью этих правок потратили время 14(!) человек. Пожалуйста, воздержитесь от минорных правок. Правки вида "стоит задача" -> "необходимо" не улучшают читабельность и ничем не помогают решению проблемы топикастера.

Comment: Слова могут идти справа налево? То есть [вот такое](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dima74/661af63f614566c74c9c188fa4abd621/raw/aaa4be61c37f02290c72999b6866a2856d75c649/gistfile1.txt) размещение слов подойдёт?

Comment: @diraria да, подойдёт.

Comment: Надо использовать все слова или как в решении hedgehogues надо выбирать слова? И вообще, сколько всего слов, порядка десяти или значительно больше?

Comment: @РодионПоляков чем Вам не нравится то, что я предложил?

Comment: @hedgehogues если не секрет, зачем ты конкурс объявил?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вопрос не достаточно конкретизирован. Предположу, что автор имеет ввиду следующее:

Пусть задан набор слов из **N**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пусть задано число **M (== 16)**. Необходимо найти такие номера слов, что их суммарная длина будет равна **M**.

**Решение 1**

Заметим, что слова, как объекты нас не интересуют. Нам интересны лишь их длины. Длины их обозначим через `l_i`. Т.е. теперь у нас есть последовательность длин слов (их даже следует назвать множеством):

[image: <code>X = {l_0, l_1, ..., l_N}</code>]

**Математически строго поставим задачу (к решению имеет косвенное отношение).**

В таком случае, нам нужно понять, существует ли решение хотя бы одного уравнения `A_k` над нашим множеством `X`:

[image: <code>A_k: x_0 + x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k = M</code>]

Т.е. существует ли решение уравнения

[image: <code>x0 = M</code>]

или

[image: <code>x_0 + x_1 = M</code>]

и т.д.

`x_i` может принимать значения из множества `X` ограниченное число раз.

**Продолжение решения**

Нам нужно найти комбинацию `l_i`, которые в сумме дадут `M`.

Отсортируем последовательность

[image: <code>l_0, ..., l_i, ..., l_N</code>]

по убыванию и выбросим все те, для которых:

[image: <code>l_i > M</code>],

так как они не смогут участвовать в финальной сумме. После сортировки имеем:

[image: <code>s_0, s_1, ..., s_p</code>],

где

[image: <code>s_i <= M, s_i >= s_{i+1}</code>].

Теперь нам нужно перебрать все варианты решения (т.к. `M=16`, т.е. небольшое, то мы в полне уложимся в перебор). Для перебора будем использовать [DFS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83).

**Как мы это будем делать**

1. Возьмём `s_0`. Проверим `s_0 != M`. Если равно, то решение найдено.
2. Попробуем подобрать для него такое число `s_i`, что `s_0 + s_i <= M`. Все варианты `i` для которых `s_0 + s_i > M` рассматривать не будет. В силу того, что объекты отсортированы, нам необходимо лишь перебрать их в порядке следования.
3. Если `s_0 + s_i = M`, то решение найдено. Если нет, то продолжаем поиск.
4. Т.е. выберем для `s_i` такое `s_j (j >= i)`, что `s_0 + s_i + s_j <= M` (аналогично пункту 2).

На некотором шаге может оказаться, что `s_0 + s_i + s_{i+1} >= M`. В таком случае дальше осуществлять перебор не имеет смысла. Это справедливо, поскольку всё элементы отсортированы.

Необходимо вернуться на предыдущий шаг и найти `s_k (k > j)`. Т.е. подобрать `s_0 + s_i + s_k <= M`. Если мы перебрали все возможные варианты, но не нашли сумму такую, что она равна `M`, то решения нет.

Для большего понимания, как следует организовать перебор, приведу псевдокод:

```
def dfs(s, sum):
    for number in get_next_number(s):
        new_sum = sum + number
        answ = False
        if new_sum == m: # Если нашли решение, то выходим из перебора
            return True
        elif new_sum < m: # Если решение не нашли, то пытаемся взять следующее число и повторить итерацию
            answ = dfs(number, new_sum)
        if answ:
            return True
    return False # Если ни в одном случае не удалось подобрать сумму, то выходим
```

`dfs` нужно запустить от каждого из имеющихся чисел `s`.

Точно сложность не могу оценить, но  дам верхнюю оценку. Она точно не больше `O(N^3)` по времени. Но следует понимать, что это завышенная оценка. Скорее всего, реальное время работы будет близко к `O(N^2)` или даже `O(N log N)`

Я также предполагаю, что можно предложить более умное решение динамическим программированием, в частности, свести эту задачу, к задаче о рюкзаке.

**Другое решение**

Для этого решения достаточно каждому слову поставить в соответствие метку `1` или `0`, которая будет обозначать: нужно ли брать в ответ слово или не нужно. Таким образом, мы имеем битовую маску, состоящую из `0` и `1`. Нам необходимо перебрать все возможные комбинации (их `2^N`), посчитав для каждой из них суммарную длину выбранных слов.

Приведу пример:

`один` // длина 4

`два_`  // длина 4

`пять`  // длина 4

`три`  // длина 3

`четыре`  // длина 6

Пусть `M = 12`.

Маска будет состоять из 5 битов. Будем начинать перебор с маски `00000`:

`10000`. Слова: `один`. Суммарная длина `4 != M`

`01000`. Слова: `два_`. Суммарная длина `4 != M`

`11000`. Слова: `один`, `два_`. Суммарная длина `8 != M`

`00100`. Слова: `пять`. Суммарная длина `4 != M`

`10100`. Слова: `один`, `пять`. Суммарная длина `8 != M`

`11100`. Слова: `один`, `два_`, `пять`. Суммарная длина `12 == M`

В ответ могут войти слова:
[`один`, `два_`, `пять`]

Спешу заметить, что вычислительная сложность алгоритма велика: O(2^N). Т.е. уже при 30 словах вы получите достаточно долго работающий алгоритм (минута или более).

**Задание размеров сетки**

Что касается сетки, то для задания её размеров можно задавать `A`, `B` -- размеры её сторон. По этим величинам вы генерируете саму сетку. `A * B = M`

**Псевдокод**

Для расположения слов, согласно вышеописанному алгоритму, можно воспользоваться "зейкой". Вы перебираете последовательно ячейки и кладёте туда по одной букве. Предварительно, разумеется, следует расположить все слова друг за другом:

```
words = 'одиндватричетыре'
letters_count = 0
for x in range(0, A):
   if x % 2 == 0:
      line = range(0, B)
   else: 
      line = range(B, 0, -1)
   for y in line:
      matrix[y][x] = words[letters_count]
      letters_count += 1
```

Comment: @РодионПоляков, Вам понятно, что я написал?

Comment: Что-то ты перемудрил. При 16 отлично работает перебор по маске. UPDATE: Стоп. Перепутал. Там суммарная длина 16, а не число слов.

Comment: @Qwertiy чего это я перемудрил? DFS запустил и вперёд. Классический подход. Это и быстрее и более общий случай. Пишется легко.

Comment: @Qwertiy Хочу конкурс стартануть. Но почему-то вопрос не разлочили.

Comment: @hedgehogues, мне на js нужно сделать. Но спасибо, может попробую переделать. p.s. язык изначально не тот поставился.

Comment: @РодионПоляков вы же умеете писать на js? В чём проблема разобраться с псевдокодом?

Comment: @hedgehogues вы же умеете писать на js? В чем проблема сразу дать ответ на том языке, который стоит в метках вопроса?

Comment: @PashaPash с javascript мне работать некомфорто. Писать на языке, который я плохо знаю, я не готов. Повторюсь, что изначально речь шла лишь об алгоритме.

Comment: @hedgehogues изначально речь шла о том как это сделать на js, о чем однозначно говорила одноименная метка на вопросе. Тот факт, что в тексте вопроса js не упоминался - это нормально, потому что текст вопроса не должен дублировать метки.