# Разделить строку на буквы и занести их в отдельную ячейку

Tags: php, массивы

Есть строка из n символов. Например строка: "я нуб в php" необходимо её разделить на символы и записать их в отдельную ячейку. и задать число столбцов. Например 4. А строк должно быть столько, сколько понадобится для того, что бы уместить весь текст
чтоб визуально выглядело так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если 11 или более столбцов, то будет всё в одну строку.

на символы то понятно как разбить, а как указать сколько мне нужно нужно столбцов сделать в данном массиве я просто не понимаю. Ткните носом хотя бы или наведите на умною мысль.

UPD: если заполнять руками, то выйдет вот так, но как делать, что бы само выстраивалось по заданному числу?

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    $text = 'очень большой текст';
    $text = preg_split('//u',$text,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $key = "привет";
    $count = mb_strlen($key);
    echo "Должно быть: ".$count. ' столбцов.';



    $a = array('о','ь','л','й','к',' '); 
    $b = array('ч',' ','ь',' ','с',' '); 
    $c = array('е','б','ш','т','т',' '); 
    $d = array('н','о','о','е',' ',' '); 

    $THN = array($a, $b, $c, $d);
    for($i=0; $i < count($THN); $i++)  
    { 
       for($q=0; $q < count($THN[$i]); $q++) 
       { 
         echo  "|".$THN[$i][$q];    
       } 
       echo "<br>"; 
    } 
?>
```

UPD 2: копаю в сторону многомерных массивов, но опять же ручками. заполнить то я заполню в цикле, но как указать, что у меня должно быть именно !4! массива, даже если я заведомо в коде укажу это. Как именно создать новый массив в цикле? будь это указана цифра 4 или 100?

```
#сюда как бы нужно заполнить массив $text, но не ручками
$myArray = array(
    array('о','ь','л','й','к',' '),
    array('ч',' ','ь',' ','с',' '),
    array('е','б','ш','т','т',' '),
    array('н','о','о','е',' ',' ')
);
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
    for ($j=0; $j <6; $j++){
        echo ' | '.$myArray[$i][$j];
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Заранее спаибо!

Comment: $columns = 4; не помогает?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов не совсем понял, что Вы имеете ввиду

Comment: Недавно такой вопрос был.

Comment: @Visman можно ссылку?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/717724/186083

Comment: @Visman Спасибо! буду мониторить тот вопрос. Вопрос схожий, может адаптирую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function make_letters_field( $string, $columns = 1 ){
    $char_array = str_split( $string );
    $row_count  = ceil( count($char_array) / $columns );
    $last_big_column_key = $columns + count($char_array) - $row_count * $columns;
    $additional_items = 0;

    $field = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($char_array); $i++){
        if( floor($i / $row_count) >= $last_big_column_key ){
            $additional_items = floor( ($i + $additional_items) / $row_count ) - $last_big_column_key + 1;
        }

        $i_key = ($i + $additional_items) % $row_count;
        if( $additional_items ){
            $i_key--;
        }

        $j_key = floor( ($i + $additional_items) / $row_count );

        $field[$i_key][$j_key] = $char_array[$i];
    }

    // заполняем пустые поля
    for($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++){
        for($j = 0; $j < $columns; $j++){
            if( ! isset($field[$i][$j]) ){
                $field[$i][$j] = '';
            }
        }
    }

    return $field;
}

$example_string = "Some text for example";       // строка для примера
$val = make_letters_field($example_string, 4);   // вызов функции. количество колонок - 4

// вывод массива с результатом
for($i = 0; $i < count($val); $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < count($val[$i]); $j++)
        echo $val[$i][$j];
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: `$val = make_letters_field($example_string, 10);` при указании 10 колонок Ваш код вывел 7 в 3 строки.

Comment: Да, ты прав. Не рассматривал ситуации, когда может быть много пустых ячеек в последней строке. Вобщем, исправил сообщение. Пробуй ;)

Comment: @SergeyKhomenko почему кодировка слетает, если указывать русские символы?

Comment: @sbaikov во второй строке замените ```$char_array = str_split( $string );``` на ```$char_array = preg_split('//u', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);``` для поддержки мультибайтых кодировок (str_split разбивает строку по байтам, а не по символам)

Comment: @SergeyKhomenko. Если указать текст "очень большой текст" 6 столбцов и 4 строки, То первый столбец всё нормально считает, а второй уже идёт по 3 символа, а низ забивает проблемами

Comment: @SergeyKhomenko кинул скрин бы, но в комментах нельзя:)

Comment: @sbaikov 19 символов в 6 столбцов... как по мне - логично... Если равное количество текста в строках важнее, то смотрите правки моего ответа и берите оттуда первоначальный вариант. Единственное, что - исправьте функцию для поддержки мультибайта

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65916/discussion-between-sbaikov-and-sergey-khomenko).

Comment: @SergeyKhomenko а впервой редакции, если ставить кол-во столбцов 5, то выводит 4, если 6 то всё нормально. Пока не нашёл закономерность. Но если указать там 4, то заполняет так как нужно. з.ы. киньте меня в чат тут, я не нашёл как это сделать)